# Refreshing a question in the Android App doesn't update the bar telling me if it's closed, bountied, etc

Tags: bug, closed-questions, android-app, active-bounties

Observed in Android App <s>v1.0.35</s> v1.0.43 on a HTC One running Android 4.4.2:

There's a banner at the bottom of questions which inform me if they're closed, there's a bounty, or they're locked. Refreshing a question doesn't appear to update this banner, or make it display or disappear as appropriate.

- If a question gets closed, refreshing it won't display the banner saying such.
- If it gets reopened, refreshing the question won't make the banner disappear.
- If it gets bountied, it won't show up on refresh either.

etc.

The only way to make the grey bar update is to leave the question altogether then re-enter it.